# Indented text not saved in answer after registering for a community for the first time

Tags: bug, draft

I just noticed the following.

I prepared an answer for a new community I wasn't registered for yet.

It contained an indented block.

After clicking on "Register for this community" the indented block disappeared in the answer before submitting it. The rest of the answer stayed intact.